# timezone conversion based on user's timezone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timezone

I'm working on an app that returns EST time. I want to convert EST time to the user's local timezone.

eg:
EST: 2022-03-23T21:00:00.000Z

PKT: 2022-03-24T06:00:00.000Z

Sydeny: 2022-03-24T12:00:00.000Z

Comment: Make your app return UTC time. Then it's easy to convert from UTC to the target time zone.

Comment: The `Z` indicates 'Zulu Time' or UTC, so you either have a `Z` or a timezone offset.

Answer (score 0):

I think time zones will be selected by default with your location ( local one ). However to convert it into another one you can use moment js library.

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone')

const start = moment.tz("2021-12-08T10:00:00", "UTC") // original timezone

console.log(start.tz("America/Los_Angeles").format())
console.log(start.tz("Asia/Calcutta").format())
console.log(start.tz("Canada/Eastern").format())
```

Comment: Thanks Asad. but I don't have the timezone string. I have user offset only

Comment: U can pass the offset to the moment as well ( maybe, please look into it's docs ) thanks and accept the answer.